# C# Sql client - can't Insert parametrized column whose name starts with number

Tags: c#, sql, insert, prepared-statement

In my `SqlClient` class, I've implemented `Insert` method this way. I have to pass `Dictionary` with pairs (column name, value) to `Insert` method and then method constructs parametrized query and executes the command.

```
    public void Insert(string table, Dictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        // build INSERT query
        string query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (";

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
            query += pair.Key + ",";

        query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 1) + ")";
        query += "VALUES (";

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
            query += "@" + pair.Key + ",";

        query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 1) + ")";

        // create command from query
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connect))
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
                command.Parameters.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

            // execute command
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

But, I found it not working while in values list is some column, whose name starts by number, for example `1column`. (I know that this is terrible variable name, tell it to database owner). Can you suggest me some way how to make it working? Also, you definitely will find my way of query building not ideal, so I will be grateful for any comments.

**EDIT**:

- Surrounding column name with double quotes (`"1column"`) doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the column name with brackets, e.g. [1column].

```
  string query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (";

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
        query += "[" + pair.Key + "],";
```

Comment: I do not believe you.  Please show the SQL command after making my changes.

Comment: Richard, I'm really sorry. I made little mistake. Now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes have no special meanings in T-SQL. Use square brackets:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
    query += "[" + pair.Key + "],";
```

Answer (score 1):

Column names may start with digits, in which case you have to surround it with []:

```
query += "[" + pair.Key + "],";
```

Parameter names, however, cannot. You need to device a strategy to convert names starting with digits to something else. For example:

```
public void Insert(string table, Dictionary<string, object> values)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (";

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
        query += "[" + pair.Key + "],";

    query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 1) + ")";
    query += "VALUES (";

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
        query += ParamName(pair.Key) + ",";

    query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 1) + ")";

    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParamName(pair.Key), pair.Value);
            }
            // execute command
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

private string ParamName(string input)
{
    return "@_" + input.Replace(" ", "_");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would makes sure that when calling the offending column, it is surrounded with ""

I.E. "1column"

It could be that the sql engine is seeing its as two seperate entities as in 1 and column.

UPDATE:

Have you tried changing

```
command.Parameters.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

for

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

Comment: That being the case, i would do what Richard suggested, output your command string out to a message box so that you can check it is generating the right string.

Comment: Finally it works with brackets, also thank you for your effort.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was it the building of the query that was incorrect?